# system of inequalities in Mathematica

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, inequality, systems-of-equations, geometric-inequalities

I am trying to solve the following system of inequalities in Mathematica but the output is just the same system of inequalities. I need to get the expressions for x, y in terms of the pi indexed constants.

I tried renaming the pi constants {a,b,c,d} but still no significant output.

I would truly appreciate your help,
PM

FindInstance[{x >= a, x + y >= b, x + 2 y >= c, y >= a, 2 y >= b, 
  2 x + 2 y == d, c == a + b, b >= 2 a, d >= 2 b}, {x, y}]

Or equivalently

FindInstance[{x >= Subscript[pi, 1], x + y >= Subscript[pi, 2], 
  x + 2 y >= Subscript[pi, 3], y >= Subscript[pi, 1], 
  2 y >= Subscript[pi, 2], 2 x + 2 y == Subscript[pi, 4], 
  Subscript[pi, 3] == Subscript[pi, 1] + Subscript[pi, 2], 
  Subscript[pi, 2] >= 2 Subscript[pi, 1], 
  Subscript[pi, 4] >= 2 Subscript[pi, 2]}, {x, y}, reals]

Comment: Try http://mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Comment: While help with solving a system of inequalities is on-topic here, as a purely mathematical problem, it is doubtful that we can help with how to convince the Mathematica software package to return a solution parameterized by $a,b,c,d$ as you apparently want to do.  Indeed I do not think it is possible to do it in the way you expect, since solutions may or may not exist when arbitrary values are assigned to $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Hint:  Instead of FindInstance, use Reduce.